# How can I send an image canvas to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs and I need to send a generated image with canvas to my nodejs server. I am using Axios to send the generated image but it is not working.

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
const textInput = document.getElementById('text');

textInput.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {

    let newText = event.target.value;
    let text = new fabric.Text(newText, { left: 100, top: 100 });

    canvas.add(text);
});


const sendPNG = () => {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      });

    console.log("image", dataURL);
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', dataURL)
        .then(res => { console.log("Test res:", res) })
}
```

This is the server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var upload = require('express-fileupload');
const http = require('http');
http.Server(app).listen(5000);

app.use(upload());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    if (req.files) {
        console.log("Image test:", req.files);
        res.json({ url : "test"})
    }
})
```

Comment: does the console have the dataURL's value?

Comment: image data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA....

Comment: can you try listening after you set your route?

Comment: When I use an imput type = "File" and use new FormData () to send, it works normally and I have the return, but when I use canvas.toDataURL doesn't work

Comment: @cemal I think it's something related to  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..